# Finding all elements in a tuple that match a condition

Tags: python, function

This is my function:

```
data = (130, 150, 200, 100, 130, 147)

def find_elevated_bloodpressure(bloodpressure, upper_limit):
    for x in bloodpressure:
        if x > upper_limit:
            return x
```

This only returns the first from the list, but I want it to return all of them.

```
find_elevated_bloodpressure(data, 140)
```

How can I get a list of all elements that match the condition `x > upper_limit`?

Comment: Well, if only there was a question anywhere in your post...

Comment: What is your function supposed to do? What are your inputs and outputs? Make up your mind and have a solid question before you post a question

Comment: In a function, when the `return` statement is encountered, the function actually comes to an end. So, when you say `return x`, your function kicks the bucket.

In your case, you need to return a list of values which are greater than the `upper_limit`.

Comment: > I am sure this is is a stupid question <. That is not an excuse for not posting that question. Usually we don't bite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build the results into a list, and return that.  Something like this:

```
data = (130, 150, 200, 100, 130, 147)

def find_elevated_bloodpressure(bloodpressure, upper_limit):
    results = []
    for x in bloodpressure:
        if x > upper_limit:
            results.append(x)
    return results
```

Answer (score 5):

when you call `return`, the function takes whatever is passed to `return`, and returns it as its only value. If you want all the elements that satisfy the conditions, you can do things like return a list comprehension:

```
return [x for x in bloodpressure if x > upper_limit]
```

Or use it as a generator

```
#return x <-- replace with yield
yield x
```